Realm actors api usage on iOS
Got this example from realm docs, realm instance like realm objects are thread-confined, so using them on other thread leads to crash, by Swift concurrency model code after await maybe executed on some other thread.
So my question is why a warning says that code below may crash only on a line after //3 but not after //1 or even //2 mark, since thread may change?
@BackgroundActor
func backgroundThreadFunction() async throws {
    // Explicitly specifying the actor is required for anything that is not MainActor
    let realm = try await Realm(actor: BackgroundActor.shared)
//1
    try await realm.asyncWrite {
//2
        _ = realm.create(Todo.self, value: [
            "name": "Pledge fealty and service to Gondor",
            "owner": "Pippin",
            "status": "In Progress"
        ])
    }
    // Thread-confined Realms would sometimes throw an exception here, as we
    // may end up on a different thread after an `await`
//3
    let todoCount = realm.objects(Todo.self).count
    print("The number of Realm objects is: \(todoCount)")
}
@MainActor
func mainThreadFunction() async throws {
    try await backgroundThreadFunction()
}


I copy and pasted your code into a project (and added @globalActor actor BackgroundActor: GlobalActor) and am not getting any warnings or messages. Is your Realm version outdated possibly?

@Rob https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/device-sdks/sdk/swift/use-realm-with-actors/
the problem that docs don't explain when thread checks are made and how actor api differs from regular api, by old logic realm should crash after //1 and after //2 but it's not clear at all

The code in your question does not crash and is @Rob straight from the documentation. It works well and leverages actors for thread related work. What's not clear is what the question is specifically and where the code is going wrong - it works. If it's not working for you, then the issue is environmental - outdated Realm, cocoapods, incorrect SPM or even another section of code.

@Rob I launched a code similar to this and just put print(Thread.current) and sometimes //1 and //2 were executed on different threads

@Jay the code works, but the question actually about architecture of Realm, does the usage of actors changes what we know from thread-confined paradigm or something else?

It does not. Realm objects are thread confined regardless of the implementation and they are tied to the Realm they are created on. To "move" them between threads, they need to be frozen and thawed. You can work with realm objects within an actor isolated realm but again, it keeps those objects within the same thread. You have options for passing them between threads - frozen/thaw and with Actors, a ThreadSafeReference which is essentially the same thing. Please keep in mind that much of Realm functionality has been depreciated and its existence past Sept 25 is in doubt.

@Jay – Are all Realm objects are thread-confined? E.g. Swift Concurrency - Swift SDK: Sendable, Non-Sendable and Thread-Confined Types suggests alternatives for Sendable, non-Sendable, and thread-confined types. No?

@Rob Yes, RLMObjects (aka Realm Objects) are thread confined and cannot passed across threads without some other mechanic (see the Tread Confined column in your link). However, they can be frozen on on thread and thawed on another. There are specialized functions for asynchronous/await as well as Actors so how you deal with thread depends on the implementation. On that note, we rarely have to worry about threading - if you're having an issue navigating that, please post a separate question.

@Jay but what is the point to use Realm actor api then? Just to use read and write on MainActor and that's all?

Traditionally using async dispatch methods enables blocking and data contention. However wrapping code within a closure makes the code more complex and it relies on escaping arguments. Actors address that in they behave more like a class so the code is wrapped in the Actor instead of a bunch of closures/escapes. As far as Realm goes - you can see the convenience of that and it protects from data races to boot.

@Jay I understand the purpose of actors, but don't see actually benefits of using them in Realm (maybe except MainActor for small read-writes), in the case of using non-main actors it looks like you still need to wrap code in a dispatch-queue to maintain thread-confined nature of Realm objects

Correct. There isn't a use-case where Actors provide big benefits in Realm. It's mostly for compatibility. And again, Realm is likely on its way out (unfortunately) so selecting another platform would be a good idea.

@Jay Realm is going to halt development? What do you recommend to use instead?

See Realm (Atlas Device SDK) Depreciation. In a nutshell, all Realm Sync functionality will be gone Sept of 25. That reduces Realm to be a local only unsupported database. There is talk of making it "open source" but it's unclear who/how that would happen. My guess is the entire project will simply go away. I do not have any great alternatives at this time but you may want to read through the very long discussion on their forums
